# Show that $N(a)= \{ x \in G | x\circ a = a \circ x \}$ is a sub-group when $(G,\circ)$ is a group.

Tags: group-theory

So, it is given that $(G,\circ)$ is a group and we have to
show that $N(a)= \{ x \in G | x\circ a = a \circ x \}$ is a sub-group when $(G,\circ)$ is a group, and $a$ is a fixed element of a group.

I am completely blank at this one.I know what properties I need to prove an algebraic structure a group, but how do I apply them here.

Please help me in moving forward.

Comment: That is not usually denoted $N(a)$, but $C(a)$, the centralizer of $a$. For a subset $X$ of $G$, $N(X)$ denotes (usually) the **normalizer** of $X$, which is the set of all $g\in G$ such that $g\langle X\rangle g^{-1}=\langle X\rangle$.

Answer (score 6):

The standard notation is $C(a)$, not $N(a)$. The **centralizer** of $a$ in $G$ is
$$ C(a) = \{ g\in G\mid ga=ag\}.$$
I will use that notation.

Well, to show that $C(a)$ is a subgroup of $G$, you need to show that:

1. $e\in C(a)$. Is it the case that $ae=ea$?
2. If $x\in C(a)$, then $x^{-1}\in C(a)$. Is it true that if $xa=ax$, then it follows that $x^{-1}a=ax^{-1}$?
3. If $x\in C(a)$ and $y\in C(a)$, then $xy\in C(a)$. If $xa=ax$ and $ya=ay$, does it follow that $(xy)a = a(xy)$?

So, check that.

Answer (score 0):

**proposition:** let $N$ be non empty subset of group$G$ then $N$ is subgroup of $G$ iff for all $a, b\in N$ implies that $ab^{-1}\in N$.

$N(a)$ is non empty because $ea=ae$ so $e\in N(a)$. So let $x, y\in N(a)$ then we have $$ax=xa, \qquad ay=ya$$
This implies that $$a=x^{-1}ax, \qquad a=y^{-1}ay$$
Now $$ axy^{-1}=xay^{-1}=x(y^{-1}ay)y^{-1}=xy^{-1}a$$
so $xy^{-1}\in N(a)$ and $N(a)$ is subgroup of $G$.

Comment: You are missing nonemptiness in your proposition. And in your verification. Because the empty set satisfies the hypotheses of your proposition, but the empty set is never a subgroup.

Comment: It is true. I'm editing the proposition. Thank you